# How to make AWS CodeBuild update a PR code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I have a TypeScript project where I have a type coverage and a test coverage, and scripts allowing them to automatically update the thresholds of these when these get any higher.
Right now, the git hooks I defined "ask" the person who pushes to manually re-push with the updated thresholds.

The project I'm working uses AWS CodeBuild as its CI. Is there a way to update these thresholds automatically, whenever there's a new PR opened and tested?

*Ideally, in the case the thresholds can be higher, it would create a new commit inside the PR named "Raising coverage thresholds".*

Comment: You can create a technical user within your git, give codebuild the credentials for it and write custom code / scripts to push something to git / to write something on the pr.

Comment: Could this be done if my buildspec file controlling the CodeBuild is in my repository files?